# Does Latin "sexus" also mean "6" in English?

Tags: classical-latin, vocabulary

I started learning Latin (self-learning), I used Oxford and online [Latin-English dictionary](https://www.online-latin-dictionary.com/)
but on translating the word "sexus" [online dictionary](https://www.online-latin-dictionary.com/latin-english-dictionary.php?parola=sexus) it gives sex and six but the book gives only sex.
Is this online translation is right because I checked other online dictionaries they only give "sex"

Comment: Welcome to the site! I think that the online dictionary you're using isn't the most solid reference as a Latin dictionary. Check out the recommendations in this question about [the best online Latin dictionary](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/867/which-online-latin-dictionaries-should-i-use-and-why) - there are a number of great choices.

Answer (score 7):

In Latin, *[sex](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sex#Latin)* is the numeral 6, and doesn't appear to have any other meanings other than as a numeral. [Sexus](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=sexus&la=la&can=sexus0) does mean gender, but does not mean 6.

Comment: why then online dic. translate it six

Comment: @AbhishekYadav. This "Latin dictionary" is rubbish. You should use a real dictionary like https://www.lexilogos.com/english/latin_dictionary.htm.

Comment: @Adam. Sexus means "sex" and genus means "gender". These are not the same thing.

Comment: @fdb Do you have a link handy for a dictionary entry that lists a meaning of _sexus_ as "sex" in the sense of fornication? Every dictionary I've looked at so far gives the meaning as something like, "the state of or spec. qualities assoc. w. being male or female, sex, gender."

Comment: @Adam [*Genus*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=genus1&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059) means "birth, descent, origin, race, stock" and similar, whereas [*sexus*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=sexus&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059) is "sex (male or female)". They can both be translated as "gender" in some senses: *genus* for a word, *sexus* for a person. Neither can stand for "sex" in the sense of intercourse.